# public clouds with similar AWS EBS offerings

Tags: amazon-web-services

What are other public clouds with similar AWS EBS offerings?

The ability to have the disks and compute to be separate and independent and you could attach/detach disk at runtime

What about the ability to set IOPS (provisioned IOPS)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are disks in both Google Compute Engine and Microsoft Windows Azure.

In Azure when you create and attach a Disk; behind the scenes it is a page-blob which gets created in the apecified Azure Storage Account. There isn't any exact same like AWS EBS in Azure. This disk can attached, reattached to instances.

https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/disks
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/06/28/exploring-windows-azure-drives-disks-and-images.aspx

Comment: can you add multiple disks to one node on both?

Comment: You can attach more than one disk i.e. Apart from the root volume. Azure has a restriction about maximum number of disks which can be attached based on the instance size. Not sure about google compute engine

Answer (score 0):

On the ability to set set IOPS, it seems that with GCE and Azure IOPS is tied to capacity. There doesn't seem to be a way to set IOPS limits as you can with AWS io1 (even though io1 is also capacity bound).

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/performance
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-premium-storage/